# Problems with AnonymousType ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I get an error and i don't know how to fix it, this is my code:

```
var respaldos = db.Respaldoes.Where(x => x.type == "Backup");

if (con_filtro_fecha)
    respaldos = respaldos.Where(x => x.start_time >= _desde && x.start_time <= _hasta);

if (con_agrupacion)
{
    switch (agrupar)
    {
        case "dia":
            respaldos = respaldos.GroupBy(x => new{
                    x.start_time.Year,
                    x.start_time.Month,
                    x.start_time.Day
                })
                .Select(x => new{
                    anio = x.Key.Year,
                    mes = x.Key.Month,
                    dia = x.Key.Day,
                    bytes = x.Sum(y => y.bytes_processed)
                }).AsEnumerable();
            break;
        case "mes":
            respaldos = respaldos.GroupBy(x => new{
                    x.start_time.Year,
                    x.start_time.Month
                })
                .Select(x => new{
                    anio = x.Key.Year,
                    mes = x.Key.Month,
                    bytes = x.Sum(y => y.bytes_processed)
                }).AsEnumerable();
            break;
    }
}
```

How to fix the error that I get in "AsEnumerable()"?
Or if this is not possible, what I can do?

Error:

> No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable AnonymousType#1  en System.Linq.IQueryable RespaldoServidores.Models.Respaldo . Ya existe una conversión explícita (compruebe si le falta una conversión)

Comment: What is the declaration of variable `respaldos`?

Comment: var respaldos = db.Respaldoes.Where(x => x.type == "Backup");

Answer (score 2):

When you call `AsEnumerable` you have 2 problems.

Firstly, `respaldos` is originally an `IQueryable<T>`, so you can't assign an `Enumerable<T>` to it.

Secondly, the element types are different. I'm not sure what type of element `respaldos` contains, but it won't be the same as the anonymous type from your query.